# Viewing video stream

Tags: configuration

I have recently signed up for a video streaming site (watch.filmstruck.com). I can sign into their website without any problem, but when I chose a movie, what appears to be their video player opens up, but nothing happens.

One of the answers I saw for a previous question about videos mentioned [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). As I understand it, this is for downloading videos. I don't want to download - I just want to stream a video.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Tor only works with TCP, so it's possible the video stream is being sent with UDP and thus Tor is unable to handle the requests.

Comment: Is there video player a standalone application, or just a player in your browser? If it is a standalone, then it will not work.

Comment: Filmstruck closed in November 2018, so this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

The player opened by your browser **does not** know a thing about your Tor settings. Edit your player settings to use Tor proxy and save them by default - that's how it will work. Or - a *better, but harder way* - use a middlebox/router to wrap all the traffic through Tor